# IoT Hub device send/receive messages via ActiveMQ

Tags: java, activemq-classic, amqp, azure-iot-hub

I'm asking for a support on a task I'm currently working on. I'm trying to connect my device to the IoT Hub via ActiveMQ. I have following reasons to do so:

- The company I'm working for currently uses own servers with ActiveMQ running on both device and server.
- We'd like to keep the ActiveMQ on devices because it handles message persistence ([Kaha DB](http://activemq.apache.org/kahadb.html)) and also covers some connection issues for us.
- I've already made a working example of messaging using [Qpid](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.qpid) libraries. It works well, but doesn't cover the persistence/connection issues.
- Current code is quite complicated and not commented, so I cannot just change the configuration file and hope everything works. Yet I have to create compatible solution.

It seems to me that no one has tried to do such thing yet. Though the ActiveMQ [declares AMQP compatibility](http://activemq.apache.org/amqp.html) and IoT Hub works with JMS + AMQP 1.0 as well (e.g. [ServiceBus example](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-bus-java-how-to-use-jms-api-amqp/)), I haven't found any support on connecting those two technologies.

So I have a few questions just to make sure I don't spend too much time on something which doesn't work in the end:

1. **Is it possible to use ActiveMQ as Azure IoT hub client?** Provided I handle device registration, SAS token handling etc.
2. **Is there any (decent) example of usage ActiveMQ with AMQP?** I haven't found any guidance on ActiveMQ client using amqp to connect to remote server, yet and it would be realy helpful to have something to begin with.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Did you find a resolution?

Comment: Haha me wondering the same thing 6 years later :D. So @MilanoNicolum did you find anything?